# Didn't receive Notification Center Observer Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, notificationcenter

Here I created a *customView: UIView* and implemented **UITextField didBegin and didEnd notificationObservers**

When set object as nil. **I'm get triggered notificationObserved(_:)**

But When I pass a (*object: self*) **I didn't receive notificationObserved.**

```
class CustomView: UIView {
  func setupView() {

        [UITextField.textDidBeginEditingNotification,
         UITextField.textDidEndEditingNotification].forEach({

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(notificationObserved(_:)), name: $0, object: self)
         })
    }

 @objc func notificationObserved(_ notified: Notification) {

        switch notified.name {
        case UITextField.textDidBeginEditingNotification:
                // Do here

        case UITextField.textDidEndEditingNotification:
               // Do here
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's actually the expected behavior. The parameter `object` in the method `addObserver(_,selector:,name:,object:)` is, as stated in the [developer documentation (here)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1415360-addobserver), "The object that sends notifications to the observer".

Since the object sending the notification is `UITextField` and not and instance of your class `CustomView`, you will never get the notification when you pass `self` in the `object` parameter.

Passing `nil` indicates that no matter the sender, you always want to receive the notification.